# Need partitioning advice for dual boot Linux Mint with Vista

Tags: linux, windows-vista, multi-boot

I'm trying to install Linux Mint 18 off DVD on my pc, which already has Vista installed. It has one small HDD, which is the C drive in Vista, and another larger HDD which shows up in Vista as drive G. They're both ntfs formatted.

I want to take half of the large HDD, and make it into a partition to install Linux into. I'm at the stage in the installation where I do this, and I'm scared I'm going to screw it up and accidentally wipe out the large HDDs contents. It's got lots of stuff on it which I really don't want to lose.

Can anyone advise? Here's the "parted" style menu it's showing me:

[image]

/dev/sdb1 (1TB) is the drive I want to use: I want to make a new 500MB partition on.

I've tried to do this but it says the size is smaller than the minimum partition, then looks like it wants to format the whole drive to ext4. So I'm
a bit stuck...

Comment: Doh I meant "Vista" not "Viata". Can't see an edit button for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by making my Linux partition with Grub installed the bootable partition and marking the windows C: drive not-bootable using fdisk.  It solved the problem of Windows wanting sda as C:. The bios just looks for the first bootable partition for the bootloader and doesn't care if it finds it on sdb.  I think it has to be a primary partition as opposed to extended, but with only a G: on your second drive you should be able to get away with making sdb2 a primary partition.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't that mean Windows is going to try to boot up off `sdb`?  I don't need to do anything with sda do I?  I thought I'd just leave that as is...

Comment: I removed the bootable flag from sda1 using fdisk after installing Ubuntu-Mate. The computer is going to boot from sdb because it boots from the first bootable media it finds based on the boot order (unless you have a bios that also lets you pick the hard drive order to boot from).  When I select Windows from Grub it passes booting up to the Windows bootloader on sda1 (Ubuntu automatically handled creating the grub entry).

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I couldn't figure out how to resize the second windows partition (the G drive) so I ended up backing everything up, deleting it completely, starting the Mint installation from scratch with root, swap and home partitions, then adding the ntfs partition back again afterwards, which showed up in windows as the G drive again.  Like you say, it now boots into sdb first, where I see the Grub menu.  If I choose windows I then get the Windows boot menu (which has a left over broken ubuntu installation which i need to get rid of, from ages ago!).  But that's another question...